# Why does DOSBox run at a slower speed when using my speakers instead of my headphones?

Tags: windows-10, audio, midi, framerate, dosbox

I noticed that whenever I play a game in DOSBox, the game runs very choppy with many dropped frames when I have no audio device plugged in to my laptop's headphone jack.

However, when I plug in headphones, the game runs perfectly smoothly, with no dropped frames or choppiness.

Why does this happen? Is there a way I can increase the performance of DOSBox when I'm using my speakers?

(In case it matters, the games I'm playing are Doom and Doom II. I'm playing on Windows 10, and I'm using VirtualMIDISynth for the music and Sound Blaster emulation for the sound effects. If I disable MIDI and configure the game to use Sound Blaster for music, it runs slightly faster, but still choppy compared to using headphones.)

Comment: What port are the headphones connected to? Are they USB headphones or the old style 2.5mm jack?

Comment: @Mokubai Traditional 3.5mm jack